# How does Spring bind form values into class variables?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

If I use a `form:form` object in Spring, I can use the commandName in order to let Spring inject the class variable values.

However, I wonder, how does the controller catch this value?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/form")
public String postForm(@ModelAttribute("item") Item item, ModelMap model)
{
    return "result";
}
```

In the above code, the `Item` is injected. However, even changing the name of this variable (or removing the modelattribute), doesn't affect that this variable is injected with the form values.

Will spring just inject the values in the first model class found, from the form? How does Spring know that it has to inject the form into the `Item item` parameter?

At first I thought the variable in the controller (POST) should have the name of commandName of the form, but it does work with other names as well, strangely enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated section in the Spring Documentation describing [the usage of @ModelAttribute on method arguments](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args).

This process is known as Data Binding on submit and is following some conventions:

1. If `@ModelAttribute` is explicitely declared with a name on an argument (your case). In this case the submitted data of the form are copied over automatically under this name. You can check yourself that it is already there in your `ModelMap` model by invoking/inspecting `model.get("item")`.
2. If there is no `@ModelAttribute` argument annotation at all, then the attribute name is assumed `from the type` essentially in your case type `Item` converts to attribute name `item` (camelCase notation) that is created for you holding a new Item with the form data-bind'ed fields. That is also there in the ModelMap (same check as above: model.get("item"))

Key point to realise is in all these cases DataBinding occurs **before** hitting your Post form RequestMapping.